# VueJs Sorting using loadash

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I am using sortBy using lodash. Here is the function

```
import { sortBy } from 'lodash.sortby';
```

```
computed: {
    visibleInsights() {
      return sortBy(this.insights.filter(insight => {
        const id = this.getInsightId(insight);
        return !this.hiddenInsights.includes(id);
      }), ['insightType.attribute']);
    },
  },
```

[image]

I 'm basically trying to sort this before rendering. But I am facing the error due to this function. is there any other way to write it down to resolve the issue. above is the written code which i am trying to execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no named export (see [the source](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.7.0-npm-packages/lodash.sortby/index.js)). `import sortBy from 'lodash.sortby'`.

Comment: It could be a comment instead of answer as you have enough reputation to comment on the question.

Comment: @RohìtJíndal Why would I comment instead of answering? The problem seems to be that OP is calling `sortBy` when it's null/a non-existent named export, so fixing the import is the answer.